# Unable to install Star Citizen 3.21 - Installer error

Tags: technical-issues, star-citizen, windows-11

Using Delta Patcher v1.6.9 and game version 3.21.0-LIVE.8779972 the launcher is not able to install the game.

A red popup is shown after pressing Install and accepting the early access disclaimer:

> Installer error
> An error has occurred during the installation process.
> Look at the logs for more details.

No logs can be found in the expected locations, reinstalling the launcher and redownloading the game data, or verifying the files has no effect.

Using Windows 11 with 200GB free on the installation drive C:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://support.robertsspaceindustries.com/hc/en-us/articles/18119567477015-Windows-11-Installation-Troubleshooting) lists several steps you can try to get the game installed and running on Windows 11.

For me the registry change command fixed the issue (after rebooting):

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "* 4095" /f
```